# Replacing data in column that has different Grouped Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that returns records with a group by statement.  However, sometimes 1 column will have different values and return multiple rows instead of a single row as intended with the Group By.

SELECT ID, Division, Team
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID, Division, Team

```
----------------------------------------
ID     Division       Team
20     Div 1            2
20     Div 2            2
20     Div 3            2
----------------------------------------
```

I'd like the query to display this instead

```
----------------------------------------
ID     Division       Team
20     Multiple         2
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: the Division Column always show the literal Multiple?

Comment: Correct, but only if they are different.

Comment: Tag the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT ID,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(Division) = MAX(Division) THEN MIN(Division)
             ELSE 'Multiple'
        END) as Division,
       Team
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID, Team
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks.  What an awesome and simply elegant solution!